# Bootstrap Navbar Not Displaying the list items

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

The bootstrap navbar is not displaying the list items and toggle button is not working.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar navbar-default fixed-top navbar-light bg-faded ">
 <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/fF1j0v/anchor.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt=""> ShivaWorks</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Am I missing something? Please help.

Comment: provide jsfiddle.

Comment: https://codepen.io/monsieurshiva/pen/YQWxqw

Comment: It's because you haven't included Javascript files.

Comment: That was it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't use `bootstrap.js` and `jquery.js` in your code.

use in the end of the code before `</html>`

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`